Need to connect a Mellanox QM8700-HS2F switch with 200gbps QSFP56 ports to a TP-Link TL-SX1008 switch with 20gbps RJ45 ports
Is there some combination of a breakout cable and/or interim switch that would allow us to do this? I wish I spoke network but I'm the founder guy. Thanks for your help.
